# CodeIgniter Validation after Step 1

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Got quite an annoying quirk going on with CI validation;

1. I have a 4 step form, has to be done this way for the user interactions.
2. Step 1 has two drop down menus; you select the data, click next, this goes to Step 2
3. In Step 2, there is further validation (just for step 2), however coming from Step 1 with 2 POST values always triggers the Step 2 form validation, this happens even before any attempt is made to POST Step 2.

Wondering how people get round this, it makes using CI validation in stepped forms a little problematic!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may alter this to fit your actual logic, but ... name your submit buttons "step1", "step2", "step3" and "step4" respectively and check which one is submitted, like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['step1']))
{
    // validate for Step 1
}
elseif (isset($_POST['step2']))
{
     // validate for Step 2
}

// etc.
```

You can do the same with a hidden input field telling which form you're submitting.

Comment: I've tried this in CI terms and it wont work. Need someone with specific CodeIgniter example to step in if possible. Also I think you misunderstand the problem.

Thanks,

Comment: There are no "CI terms" for this, unless you insist that `$this->input->post()` is used for checking instead of `$_POST`, which is pointless in this case. You just need to validate only the fields for the form that is submitted.

Comment: I meant for the logic you provided it didn't translate to CI method very well, never the less the issue is solved.